# Intersection points between ellipse and line - ellipse can be rotated center is not origin

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to find the intersection of line & ellipse where ellipse is rotated and center is not a origin.
I have following:
Line :

- Slope, starting point.

ellipse

- Major and minor axis, rotation , center point

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 2):

If $Guv$ is the coordinate system in which the ellipse has Cartesian equation:

$$
u^2 + v^2 = 1
\tag{1}
$$

the *geometric transformation* that relates $Oxy$ to $Guv$ is:

$$
\begin{cases}
x = x_g + a\,u\cos\alpha - b\,v\sin\alpha \\
y = y_g + a\,u\sin\alpha + b\,v\cos\alpha \\
\end{cases}\,.
\tag{2}
$$

Therefore, the line of Cartesian equation:

$$
(y - y_p)\cos\beta = \sin\beta\,(x - x_p)
\tag{3}
$$

transforms into the line of Cartesian equation:

$$
c\,u - d\,v + e = 0,
\qquad \text{with:} \quad
\begin{aligned}
& c \equiv a\sin(\beta-\alpha)\,; \\
& d \equiv b\cos(\beta-\alpha)\,; \\
& e \equiv (x_g - x_p)\sin\beta - (y_g - y_p)\cos\beta\,. \\
\end{aligned}
\tag{4}
$$

So, intersecting $(1)$ with $(4)$ we get:

$$
u = \frac{-c\,e \pm |d|\sqrt{c^2+d^2-e^2}}{c^2+d^2}, 
\quad \quad
v = \frac{d\,e \pm c\frac{|d|}{d}\sqrt{c^2+d^2-e^2}}{c^2+d^2}
\tag{5}
$$

and applying $(2)$ we get the intersection points in the $Oxy$ coordinate system.